# Data structures: explanation of pop, push, dequeue, enqueue in this type of exercise

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I'm trying to become more comfortable with these 4 concepts.

So if we had an array of `{15, 34, 23, 32, 15, 5}`

and we had operations such as

```
pop();
push(30);
enqueue(40);
dequeue(100);
```

pop() would just remove the first number, which is 15, right ?
what if it was pop(20) ?

I'm assuming push(30) would add 30 as the last number.

Do enqueue and dequeue work the same as pop and push?

(Then would enqueue(40) add 40 at the back of the line? What would dequeue(100) do ?)

Comment: do you really want to perform these operations on an array? Maybe you should consider to be more specific and use queues/stacks?

Comment: Well I'm just trying to understand the concepts. The array is just something that I could see the demonstration on more clearly

Comment: C++ array as in std::array does not have these operations. push and pop are available in std::stack, and std::stack::pop() returns an element and does not take any arguments (pop(20) is not possible), push puts elements at the top of the stack, not at the end. There is no enqueue and dequeue in std library, but std::vector and std::deque have specific operations which are explicit about the placement of elements: push_back, pop_front, etc.. Just look up the manual of these structures.

Comment: @vexomrs: Please don't forget to come back to consider up-voting and accepting a response if you found it useful. It benefits you, those trying to answer your questions, and the community at large. That's how we say "thank you" here.

Answer (score 10):

> pop() would just remove the first number, which is 15, right ? what if
>   it was pop(20) ?

I think it'd be easier for you to understand the concepts if you associate the operations with specific data structures.

For example, operations like `push(item)` and `pop()` are meant for a *stack* while operations like `enqueue(item)` and `dequeue()` are meant for a *queue*, both of which have specific and well defined behaviors.

Stacks only work with the item at the *top*, like a stack of pancakes, papers, or any other collection of items that get placed on top of each other.

This means that your `{15, 34, 23, 32, 15, 5}` array could be viewed like this:

```
| 15 |   <--- top
| 34 |
| 23 |
| 32 |
| 15 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Here, `pop` would simply remove the element at the top and then leave `top` pointing to the element immediately below it (i.e. 34). Obviously, using `push(8)` would add a new element (i.e. 8) at the top of the stack, so it would now look like this:

```
|  8 |   <--- top
| 34 |
| 23 |
| 32 |
| 15 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Due to the stack's defined behavior, an operation like `pop(item)` would not make sense: it would no longer be limiting itself to the item at the *top* of the stack.

> I'm assuming push(30) would add 30 as the last number.

This would be incorrect, or at least ambiguous: Where do you consider the "last" element to be? What does "last" mean to you? The problem here is that terms like "first" and "last" imply order, which is something *queues* are meant for (see later). However, *stacks* are not ordered collections in this sense, so speaking about first/last elements in the context of a stack wouldn't make much sense.

In terms of stack operations like `push`ing and `pop`ing, you should always talk about the *top* or the *bottom* of the stack.

> Do enqueue and dequeue work the same as pop and push?

No. Operations like `enqueue` and `dequeue` are meant for a different data structure called a *queue*. Queues are different from stacks in how they behave and the operations they support.

For example, while a stack *always* adds or removes elements at the top, queues *always* add (i.e. `enqueue`) items at the back of the collection and remove (i.e. `dequeue`) elements at the front, in First-In-First-Out (FIFO) order.

```
 +-- front
 v
+--+----+----+----+----+---+
15 | 34 | 23 | 32 | 15 | 5 | 
+--+----+----+----+----+---+
                         ^
                         +-- back
```

If you think of a queue's behavior in terms of a line at a store, then it'd be easier to associate the correct behavior of the structure. Every time you're in a line at the store, you're in a queue.

> Then would enqueue(40) add 40 at the back of the line?

Correct. The queue would now look like this:

```
 +-- front
 v
+--+----+----+----+----+---+----+
15 | 34 | 23 | 32 | 15 | 5 | 40 |
+--+----+----+----+----+---+----+
                              ^
                              +-- back
```

> What would dequeue(100) do?

This is similar to the issue I described with `pop`: it wouldn't make sense because `dequeue` is meant to *always* remove the element at the front. Therefore, a queue would only support `dequeue()` and it would automatically remove whatever's at the front of the "line":

```
 +-- front
 v
+--+----+----+----+----+---+
34 | 23 | 32 | 15 | 5 | 40 |
+--+----+----+----+----+---+
                         ^
                         +-- back
```